# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'caffe2_nvrtc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am using anaconda and created one virtual environment named **myenv1**. After activating my virtual environment, I have installed pytorch using following command.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

But if I am trying to import torch in a filename.py it's giving following error.

```
 Could not find module 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\myenv1\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_nvrtc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

After navigating to the above path which I am getting in the error console,I am able to see this **caffe2_nvrtc.dll** .

Comment: You may find the answer you are looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021601/pytorch-could-not-find-module/62786223#62786223)